# How to run Jmeter performance scenarios through maven project?

Tags: java, maven, performance-testing, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have created some scenarios for my web application in Jmeter. I want to automate the process in maven project so that i can get good result as well as proper graphical representation.

What should i do to setup maven project which will take .jmx files created in Jmeter as input and runs.

I googled it, there i found some solutions but no solution is from scratch.
As i am new to this, i dont know how to download maven plugin/repository.

Please tell me what steps i need to follow.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for a step by step tutorial?

Comment: I am not getting from where i should download repository, do i need to create it, from where i will get pom.xml, and other needful files. I am new in this stuff and i am confused from google answers. So yes, if i get step by step tutorial to configure, that would be really helpful and informative

Comment: So this question is about maven and not jmeter. Maybe edit your question and make it about maven?

Comment: I think i have mentioned in summary about maven. anyways, i have removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done from scratch, but the Maven JMeter plugin has made it easier.

http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/

The documentation there makes it pretty easy.

1. Add Plugin to your Project
2. Put your JMX files in src/test/jmeter
3. run : mvn verify

There is a google group for that plugin as well https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/maven-jmeter-plugin-users.